# Embedding JasperReports into a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am using the *JasperReports Server Community Edition* and the *iReport* designer to create reports. I want to be able to embed these deployed reports into web application.
On the Jasperserver website it says about using an *iFrame* to embed reports that skips user authentication by providing the login credentials as arguments to the url.

Where can I find the documentation for using *iFrames* for reports?

Comment: This question is being voted to be closed because you solve this problem with google ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have the answer http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/embedding-using-http-api, using HTTP API